# To show that $\mathfrak{m}B \neq B$ for all maximal ideals $\mathfrak{m} \subset A$, where $B$ is finitely generated as $A$-module

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $B \supset A$ be an extension of commutative rings such that $B$ is finitely generated as $A$-module. Prove that $\mathfrak{m}B \neq B$ for all maximal ideals $\mathfrak{m} \subset A$.

I have no idea how to proceed. I think it should be enough to show proper inclusion. Any help?

Comment: Did you try this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakayama%27s_lemma?

Comment: Ah! Didn't strike me. Lemme give it a go. Thanks!